# How to be sure my XMPP user has no vCard using the XMPPFramework?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, vcf-vcard

I'm developing an XMPP iOS application based on [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) and an [ejabberd Community Edition server](http://www.ejabberd.im) and I'm playing around with vCard management.

During my experiments, I've found out that when requesting a vCard for a user via something like:

```
[vCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:myJID];
```

Then no delegate method will be called if the user has no vCard on the server.

Is there a way to be 100% sure a user has no vCard via an explicit answer from the server?

Or should I just consider that the user has no vCard after a delay of *n* seconds without any delegate feedback? (which would be ambiguous with the situation of a network latency that can be very frequent on a mobile environment)

Answer (score 2):

In XEP-0054 XMPPvCardTempModule.m

You need to do this

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {


    XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [self myvCardTemp];//check if exist or not

    if (!myvCardTemp)//if not then create a new vcard
    {
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
        [newvCardTemp setNickname:userName];
        [self updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
    }

}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: In [self myvCardTemp], myvCardTemp is also declared as a class variable? Also [self updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp],  updateMyvCardTemp seems to be a method declared in the same class not a delagate or xmppFramework method by the way you call it. Thank you in advance!